# Chrome locale pages edit

Tags: google-chrome

Can I edit Google Chrome local pages?

for example, chrome://version/

I've never done anything like this before.  but I need it now. Please help me

Comment: its for extension. i mean, just for me. Not extension

Comment: You'll need to modify the source code and build Chrome yourself. If you're lucky some parts of the UI may be inside resources.pak in the directory of the browser. There are tools to unpack/repack this file.